# ASP.NET 4.5 Precompiled Web Application Project deployed, but IIS/Asp.net still precompiles

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, precompile

I have an asp.net 4.5 web application project, which was precompiled via the Publish feature on VS 2015.  I can see all of the .compiled files as well as their corresponding .dll/.pdb files.  When I copy the entire website structure to the web server (IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012R2) and paste it into the physical path for my website, IIS/ASP.NET goes off and tries to precompile the entire application again.  Why?  How does one tell IIS/ASP.NET to skip that step?  The .compiled files are in my web site's bin directory, as are their corresponding .dll/.pdb files. 
Shouldn't IIS/ASP.NET see that and abort any precompliation?

Removing the  element from the web.config file did nothing.
I tried specifying a local directory for  \website\precompiled" >, and that simply put the duplicate precompiled files there instead of in ASP.NET Temporary Files.  I even put the same .dll from that directory and from my bin directory into JustDecompile, and verified that they are the exactly the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show up your config file code.

Comment: How come you know that your IIS is compiling your files again?

Comment: Here is the relevant part of the web.config file:
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" optimizeCompilations="true"  strict="true" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" tempDirectory="c:\_assets\customers\testsite\precompiled" >

Comment: I know that IIS/ASP.NET is compiling again because I can see the exact same files that are precompiled in my \bin directory in the tempDirectory specified in <compilation>